# Reusing JSS Components in SXA site

Tags: sxa, jss

I have setup a sample Angular JSS app, created a few ng components and deployed it to Sitecore instance which has a SXA site already present

I am now looking at how I can re-use or integrate my new JSS components into SXA. Is this scenario possible and what level of customization(if possible) will required to LayoutService to achieve the same

Comment: AFAIK, the Sitecore JSS components can't be used in Sitecore SXA Implementation because they way of rendering for both tech stack are different. We can utilize Sitecore SXA Site Management in the Sitecore JSS based site implementation.

Comment: OOTB its not possible, but I want to customize LayoutService and want to get a definite YES/NO around that , basis which I need to go back to my client

Comment: As per slack your requirement is to run JSS component inside the Sitecore SXA then i think its possible via IFRAME only.

Comment: And other option is: you can build pure Client side scripting based components in ReactJS/AngularJS which will be self hosted components i.e. you will just add component with required JS add-on and component will render. This thing you can control from custom SXA component parameters.To get data there will be service layer in your JS proj which will call service for appropriate environment and send the data to FE component in the form of properties so that FE component can render.Service layer in your Client side project can call JSS layout service or any required data source as per your need